# Alternative Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android-studio

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER
    };

    Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    c.moveToFirst();
    int nameColumn = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int phoneColumn = c.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
    if( c.getCount() > 0 ) {
        do{
            String name = c.getString(nameColumn);
            String phoneNumber = c.getString(phoneColumn);

            Toast.makeText(this, name+":"+phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } while(c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what error you are getting? Any logs?

Comment: The Logcat said java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.chap16_1/com.mycompany.chap16_1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column number

Comment: Can you add that to your original post with code formatting so that it's easier to read?

Comment: I don't know how to post T.T If you give me your e-mail address, I will send files and log cat snapshot...

Comment: Oh I solved it. The designated table were different, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER